# AngularJS using ng-switch without wrapper div

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use ng-switch because I do not want the other elements that I do not want to show to be part of the DOM.  That is why i did not use ng-hide/ng-show.  In the example below, I would like to only have the `span` tag be in the DOM without the div wrappers from the ng-switch.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
<div ng-switch on="user">
    <div ng-switch-when="true">
        <span>One</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="false">
        <span>Two</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the ng-switch-when on the span itself?

Comment: yeah i tried putting the ng-switch-when on the span but theres still the div wrapper from the ng-switch.

Comment: the angular ui project has an ui-if directive that will probably work for you.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use the ng-switch directive as a custom element and not specify the div in the first place.  For example:

```
<ng-switch on="user">
  <span ng-switch-when="true">One</span>
  <span ng-switch-default>Two</span>
</ng-switch>
```

Here is a plunker to play around with: http://plnkr.co/edit/zni6raUWOguhQh9jDiY3

Comment: This needs to be accepted as correct answer.  Seeing it makes me INSTANTLY understand why I was wrong.  Thank you very much

Comment: one thing to note about this, though it does not wrap the `<span/>` tags in a `<div/>` it does however wrap it in `<ng-switch/>` so if you're wanting to use a child css selector such as `body > span` it will not satisfy. but since that was not an original concern-- no biggie.

Comment: I've got problems with this solution when `<ng-switch>` comes between parent and child flex-box divs (Chrome 46).

Comment: it is the incorrect answer, ng-switch anyway works as a div element

Answer (score 1):

the solution provided by @ChrisAuer this still creates a wrapping element. 
AFAIK you'd have to use a custome directive. You may want to use [`angular-ui` `if`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#if)

```
<div ui-if="user">
    <span>One</span>
</div>
<div ui-if="!user">
    <span>Two</span>
</div>
```

Probably, in your case, you'd be fine using `ng-show` or `ng-hide` which only hide(`display:none`) the element - they don't remove it form the `DOM`.

```
<div ng-show="user"> <!-- same as ng-hide="!user" -->
    <span>One</span>
</div>
<div ng-hide="user"> <!-- same as ng-show="!user" -->
    <span>Two</span>
</div>
```

Comment: incorrect, it does not create a wrapping div. at least in my version of angular

Answer (score 1):

I would say use `ng-if`, like this:

```
<div>
    <div ng-if="user==true">
        <span>One</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="user==false">
        <span>Two</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah ng-if is a better way for me also. but im not sure if there was already 1.2.xx version of angularJS on the date this question was asked. ng-if is new on 1.12.xx version

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<span>` to prevent your html layout changing 
because `<span>` is not like `<div>`, it won't take up any space.

```
<span ng-switch="user">
  <span ng-switch-when="true">One</span>
  <span ng-switch-default>Two</span>
</span>
```